# Como pegar dados recebidos em JSON e armazenar em uma classe

Tags: android, gson

Boa tarde!

Estou com dificuldade na implementação do código para resgatar os dados que estão vindo em JSON e armazenar esses dados em uma classe.

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço, desta já.

Minha ideia é receber os dados do webservice e armazenar esses dados do Json na classe de usuário, pois utilizarei esses dados para gravar no banco de dados do aplicativo.

Segue abaixo o trecho do meu código

```
//Cria e inicializa um objeto Gson
Gson gsonUsuario = new Gson();

//Passa os dados que estão nas variaveis para o parametro
Transmissao_Env transmissao_env = new Transmissao_Env();
transmissao_env.setEmail(email);
transmissao_env.setSenha(senha);
transmissao_env.setFuncao(funcao);

//Realiza conexão com o servidor webservice e passa os parametros junto
String resultado = ToolBox.comunicacao("http://www.meusite.com.br/ws/index.php", gsonUsuario.toJson(transmissao_env));

//Pega o valor antes da tag WSTAG que foi recebida do webservice
String parRes[] = resultado.split("#WSTAG#");

//Verifica a quantidade de caracteres
switch (parRes.length) {
    case 2:

        //Verifica se o resultado do webservice foi gerado corretamente(0)
        if (parRes[0].equals("0")) {
            //Realiza a conversão do Json para um objeto do tipo
            Usuario mUsuario = gsonUsuario.fromJson(parRes[1], Usuario.class);

            //Neste ponto que preciso de ajuda
            mUsuarioDao = new UsuarioDao(mContext);
            mUsuarioDao.insereUsuario(mUsuario);
```

Os dados estão sendo recebidos na String resultado e a classe Transmissao_Rec tem os métodos ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para converter dados do JSON para objecto, eu aconselho o uso do Gson que voce esta utilizando ou libraries como o [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) que permitem fazer o request e mapear directamente o Json a um objecto. Mas sugiro que numa primeira fase voce faca o parsing  "manualmente" utilizando a classe [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) e voce pode ter mais controlo sobre todos os elementos. 
Um exemplo simples de como fazer isto:

Imagina que temos uma String com a resposta de um um utilizador

"{"utilizador":{"nome":"john","idade":19}}"

e que temos uma class Utilizador com os mesmo campos. Para fazer o parsing :
1- Criamos um Json Object da resposta passando a string :
 JSONObject resposta = new JSONObject(resposta);

2- pegamos o objecto utilizador : JSONObject utilizador = resposta.getJSONObject("utilizador"); **Note que nesta segunda chamada nos utilizamos o primeiro objecto da resposta e utilizamos a chave do objecto para pegar o objecto**

3- Podemos pegar o nome e a idade fazendo String nome = utilizador.getString("nome"); por ai em diante

4- Com os atributos do nosso objecto extraídos, basta só criar uma instância do Utilizador e ja esta.

Entrei muito por este processo pois ajuda a perceber erros cometidos muitas vezes ao utilizar libraries onde por exemplo colocar um dos atributos na classe com o nome diferente das chaves no JSON que pode resultar em um erro.

Veja este[código](https://github.com/realdm/MyMooviApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/app/mymooviapp/loaders/MovieDetailsLoader.java) que escrevi há alguns meses para fazer o parse de JSON's um pouco mais complicados